# Website as well as Snapshots show "technical difficulties"

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Without me being on the website, it suddenly shows the message: "The site is experiencing technical difficulties." I noticed this at the beginning of the month. Yet the Analytics account indicates it must have started at 31.05.

I am using Google Cloud Compute Engine, Wordpress "click to deploy platform" from "virtual machines".

Even reinstalling Snapshots from before this started does not bring me a working website again. It always shows the same error.

Please help me. Does anyone have any ideas? Or do I have to set up everything again from the beginning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies if you have Google Analytics for WordPress by MonstorInsights installed.

The problem is caused by one of the latest releases. Their release did not include the file `lite/includes/admin/wp-site-health.php`.

The solution is to connect to your instance via SSH. Then go to the WordPress Plugin directory `/wp-content/plugins` and rename the directory `google-analytics-for-wordpress`. This disables the plugin. You should be able to login to WordPress. Go to plugins and update Google Analytics for WordPress by MonstorInsights.

Update:

I forgot to mention to check the Apache logs. Check the logfile apache2/logs/error_log. Use `tail` and look at the last couple of errors. This will help you figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok, I finally took the time to learn about Linux Debian languages and accessed through ssh. I do not use google-analytics-for-wordpress. The error was with imagify though.

Thank you for your support,